# How to use serve_dir() of tide http framework to serve directory to client side?

Tags: rust

I am trying to serve files under directory by using `serve_dir()`from Tide framework. Here is the [docs](https://docs.rs/tide/latest/tide/struct.Route.html#method.serve_dir).
After I ran the server and do curl operation in my local machine terminal `curl http://serveraddress/git`, nothing get download from targeted server directory to my local machine. I expected the file under `/srv/git` should appear in my local machine.

Am I wrong?
Is there any other operation that client need to do in order to receive files?

Here is the code:

```
async fn main() -> tide::Result<()> {
let mut app = tide::new();
//client want to download the repo inside /src/git folder
app.at("/git").serve_dir("/srv/git")?;
app.listen("192.168.142.117:3000").await?;
Ok(())
```

}

Comment: Note that `curl` only downloads single files, so `curl http://serveraddress/git` will only download a single file named `git`, that will probably contain the content listing for the `git` folder.

Comment: @Jmb Thanks for replying. Shouldn't this “/git be the endpoint? I thought the meaning of `curl http://192.168.142.117:3000/git` is curl send request to endpoint /git, and then do the work of serve_dir(). But there is no file named `git` appear in my local machine.

Comment: `git` is the endpoint, but that's simply the folder you've configured, so here it's `/srv/git`. This doesn't change the fact that `curl` can only retrieve a single file. I don't know what `tide` returns in this case, but it is likely either an empty file or an HTML file containing the list of file names in `/srv/git`.

Comment: What `serve_dir` does is that if you have a file named `foo` in `/srv/git`, then `curl http://192.168.142.117:3000/git/foo` will download that single file. If you want to download the folders recursively, you need a client that can do it (which `curl` isn't).

Comment: You might try `wget` instead of `curl`, e.g. `wget --recursive http://192.168.142.117:3000/git`

Comment: @Jmb Thanks for your help and advice of downloading folders recursively. I tried `curl http://192.168.142.117:3000/git/foo.txt` and it's worked. Thanks a lot.